# Compare Local checkout version with SVN current version

Tags: java, svn, svnkit, svn-checkout

It is possible to check the locally checkout revision number with repository current version.

i.e I checkout a file from repository and made changes locally, before i commit other user checkout the same file and made changes and committed the file. Before commit i need to check whether the local revision and repository version are same or not. so that intimate the user about the revision incompatibility.

Comment: I guess no.Revisions are only logged on server

Comment: How to get the current repository version.

Comment: Are you using tortoise at client end?

Comment: I am using svnkit 1.3.5 jar file to implement the svn functionlity in my application.

Comment: You didn't mentioned that You are trying to find the implementation in code and not even tagged to Java.I had been thinking that You are trying manaully.Please Always post question precisely

Comment: I think you should use SVNStatusClient#doStatus with remote=true parameter. It's an analogue of "svn status -u".

Answer (score 0):

SVN does not allow to same changes directly if you have old copy then SVN in your local.
On every commit it change the revision of the file update. And at the time of commiting those changes it will show the difference and will ask to marge or override the changes and difference made by someone else after you pulled.

Also you can use the option "SVN Show Log" and it will show all the updated files If you double click on any of the file it will show the comparision in your working file and the file on SVN.

You can right click on the folder/file and can see the Revision of the file and folder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to compare your local file with the latest version in the repository.

The "diff" command will compare your local file with the version you checked out:

> http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.diff

You may also want to use the "status" command to see if anything has changed in the repository since your checkout:

> http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status

If neither of these is exactly what you want, I'm sure you can find what you are looking for by browsing those pages a bit.

Comment: I am using svnkit 1.3.5 jar file to get the version details. How can i get the difference using svnkit jar file

Comment: Sorry.  Never heard of it.  :(